# Output/Input of Java Files via GUI

Tags: java, file-io

I have three classes libraryDB, libraryItems and libraryGUI. libraryDB() is essentially a hash map with the keys as book barcodes/ISBN's and the values are libraryItems, which consist of and therefore take two String parameters: Title and Author.

I have a JFileChooser all set up in the GUI to save, but my save() and open() methods are giving problems. I want it set up so that when it is saved each libraryDB object has its own 3 lines (one each for Barcode, Title, Author, respectively). I tried loading them back in by reading each individual line in, here is the code I wrote for that:

```
//Suppose to construct a LibraryDB by reading one from a previously-saved file.
    public LibraryDB (File file) throws IOException {
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(file);
        int barcode;
        String title;
        String author;

        while (readFile.hasNext()){
            barcode = Integer.parseInt(readFile.nextLine());
            title   = readFile.nextLine();
            author  = readFile.nextLine();
            LibraryItem authorTitleValues = new LibraryItem(title,author);
            this.libraryItems.put(barcode, authorTitleValues);
            }
    }
//Trying to save to text file, where for each object n there are 3n lines.
    public void save(File file) throws IOException {
    PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(file);
    for (Iterator<Integer> localIterator = libraryItems.keySet().iterator(); 
    localIterator.hasNext();){ 
        int barcode = ((Integer)localIterator.next()).intValue();
        writer.println(barcode);
        writer.println((libraryItems.get(Integer.valueOf(barcode))).getTitle());
        writer.println((libraryItems.get(Integer.valueOf(barcode))).getAuthor());
        }
    }
```

Any help or insight that you can provide that will aid me in successfully being able to save/open would be much appreciated! Thanks!

More explicity, whenever I save a libraryDB to a file I am unable to go back later and open up the file?

Comment: Can you tell us what the exact problem is?

Comment: When I save a file it will not allow me to go back and open it again, sorry for not being more explicit. Perhaps there is some incompatibly somewhere?

Comment: Have you checked if that file is serialized properly? Does it have the rows it should have?

Comment: No, how might I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just forgot to redeclare libraryDB!? Grrr...lol I don't think the compiler will complain because it has already been declared. However, the information being read from the file was just going into oblivion or something because there was no object for it to be put into. At least, that is what I think was happening. Thanks for your help. Here is my solution:

```
public LibraryDB (File file) throws IOException {
//this next line was what I was missing...sigh.
    this.libraryItems = new HashMap<Integer, LibraryItem>();
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(file);
        int barcode;
        String title;
        String author;
        while (readFile.hasNext()){
            barcode = Integer.parseInt(readFile.nextLine());
            title   = readFile.nextLine();
            author  = readFile.nextLine();
            LibraryItem authorTitleValues = new LibraryItem(title, author);
            libraryItems.put(Integer.valueOf(barcode), authorTitleValues);
            }
        readFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `flush()` and `close()` your `PrintStream` before ending the `save` function. I'm not sure that is the problem, since your description is not too accurate, but do it anyway.

Comment: You should explain more what is happening... "not working" is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

File streams and writer have to be explicitly closed at the end of writing to them - otherwise they will lock the file.

```
public void save(File file) throws IOException {
    PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(file);
    try {
        for (Iterator<Integer> localIterator = libraryItems.keySet().iterator(); localIterator.hasNext();) {
            int barcode = ((Integer) localIterator.next()).intValue();
            writer.println(barcode);
            writer.println((libraryItems.get(Integer.valueOf(barcode))).getTitle());
            writer.println((libraryItems.get(Integer.valueOf(barcode))).getAuthor());
        }
        writer.flush();
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```